# Avoid a Validation Rule to be ran for seccond time

Tags: apex, validation-rule

I have a validation rule which is running twice (one when creating an Opp, and then in a `@future` method ) i need it only run the first time, and not the second.
Any tip?
the problem is with the `isnew()`, because the first time its a new opp, but the second its not.

---

validation:

```
AND (
    NOT(ISNEW()), 
    OM_R1_Number_of_attr_Industry_SubSegment__c = 0, 
    (
        TEXT(CROperatingGroup__c) = 'Health & Public Service' || 
        TEXT(CROperatingGroup__c) = 'Products'
    ), 
    OpportunityValidationBypassBoolean__c 
)
```

---

Apex Class:

```
public static void populatevalueInUserRelatedfield(set<ID> setOpportunity){

        list<Opportunity> lstToUPdate = new list<Opportunity>();        
        if(setOpportunity == null || setOpportunity.size() ==0 ){return;}

        list<Opportunity> lstOppLocal = [Select id, CreatedBy.EmployeeNumber, CreatedBy.Enterprise_ID__c from opportunity where id in : setOpportunity];


        if(lstOppLocal != null && lstOppLocal.size()>0){            
            for(Opportunity eachOpportunity : lstOppLocal){                 
                    eachOpportunity.CreatedByEmployeeNumber__c  =   eachOpportunity.CreatedBy.EmployeeNumber;
                    eachOpportunity.CreatedByEnterpriseID__c = eachOpportunity.CreatedBy.Enterprise_ID__c ;
                    lstToUPdate.add(eachOpportunity);

            }           
            if(lstToUPdate!= null && lstToUPdate.size() >0){                
                update lstToUPdate ;
            }
        }  

    }    


}
```

Comment: I am confused, you say it is running when inserted yet you have the NOT ( ISNEW()) so do you want it to run when inserted or do you not want it to run when inserted?

Comment: The first time it run asking for the isNew() its related to the opp, so, it follow the code order with no problems, but when running the @future proppery ( populatevalueInUserRelatedfield() ) it't not a new opportunity anymore because it's allready created, do i explain myself?
Thaks in advance

Comment: The VR will be TRUE if Oppo is being updated AND the other 3 conditions are true; the VR will be FALSE if Oppo is being inserted.  It is still unclear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

you can bypass the validation rule using a custom field which is set during the second @future method call.  Using a workflow rule you then reset the variable after the transaction so that further updates will cause the validation to fire as expected.

Example:

http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2011/11/bypass-validation-rules-from-apex.html

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  +1